# How to reference a Git commit by message text under Msys2

Tags: windows, git, msys2

Git provides many ways for referencing commits, other than by their SHA ID. This includes an option to find the most recent commit by a [message that matches some text string](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emlttextgtemegemfixnastybugem) using an expression of the form `:/<text>`.

When running this command in Bash under Msys2, the search text is [converted into a Windows filesystem path](https://www.msys2.org/docs/filesystem-paths/), presumably because it is confused by the use of the `:/` characters:

```
$ git rebase :/'fix nasty bug'
fatal: invalid upstream 'C:/tools/msys64/fix nasty bug'
```

Under Unix systems this commit referencing method is a handy shortcut to avoid typing out commit SHA IDs. How can this be used on Windows with Msys2 as well?

Comment: what happens if you do `':/fix nasty bug'` to avoid expansion?

Comment: No combination of quoting or escaping various characters has helped, unfortunately

Comment: The Msys2 documentation you linked does seem to suggest that running the command as `MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL='*' git...` (to disable all expansion) or possibly `MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL=':/' git...` might work.

Comment: Yes, setting the environment variable `MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL=':/'` solves the problem as you suggest. If you post an answer I'll mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MSYS2 documentation you linked](https://www.msys2.org/docs/filesystem-paths/) shows a way to disable path conversion for a command.

This can either be disabled entirely by setting the environment variable `MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL` to `*`, or it can be set to a semicolon separated list of argument prefixes which will be excluded from conversion.

In your specific case, you can run the command as `MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL=':/' git rebase :/'fix nasty bug'`